# replace assert with if statement in java android studio

Tags: java, android, assert, assertion

I've seen some Q&As on stackoverflow that say assert gets removed from released version of apk and only works in debug versions. now I see that android studio has a suggestion that says `"replace 'assert' with 'if' statement"`.
 I thought assert was something new to prevent/avoid null pointer exceptions.

1. does android gradle remove assert like it removes comments from release?
2. why does android studio/sdk even have assert if it's not gonna work in release version.
3. I have used assert everywhere I didn't check for null with an if statement (and android studio always suggested assert, and not an if stement in the first place)

Answer (score 1):

assert is just a keyword to test if a boolean is true or false.

1. don't think so, but I'm not sure
2. it's as you already mentioned, just for debugging, to test for example, if a return value isn't null before you use it
3. you should replace it with an if statement, because assert will throw an error if the boolean condition is false, so it's not recommended for the release version because the app would just crash if the condition is false.